# How to effectively waterproof an exterior vent cap?

Tags: ducts, sealing, exhaust-vent, flashing, weatherproof

This is a follow-up to my [other question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/293014/how-can-i-fix-range-hood-mounting-holes-in-an-mdf-cabinet). My house has a wood frame and vinyl siding.

Installer came out to do a range hood install and for the outdoor vent cap he just sealed it with silicone to the siding. Allegedly he sealed the duct opening to the sheathing as well, but I have no way of knowing unless I take it down.

I'm worried about the weatherproofing of the job, so I've frantically been doing research on how to fix it. I *think* I have figured out how best to do it:

1. Cut a square hole in the siding
2. Remove a few pieces of siding in the work area
3. Cut diagonally to create a flap in the house wrap on the top side of the vent hole
4. Silicone the top and sides (not bottom) of the vent cap and screw it into the wall
5. Seal the sides, then the top of the vent to the wall with flashing tape - top strip goes directly on the wood under the flap of house wrap
6. Reattach the house wrap over the top of the vent and reseal with house wrap tape
7. Surround the vent with J channel, tape the flange of the top J channel piece with house wrap tape
8. Reattach siding
9. From the other side of the wall, fill the gap between the duct and the exterior wall with firestop foam

[Here is a crude graphical depiction of what I'm thinking of.](https://imgur.com/a/lM7fa0W)

TLDR: Flash it like a window, use J channel trim, foam to seal the air gap

Does this sound reasonable? Is there any gotchas I've overlooked?

Additionally, I'm a little confused about how to approach the "not sealing the bottom" guideline regarding the gap in the exterior wall. Should I not be sealing it all around somehow?

My references:

- [How To Install J Channel (Vinyl Siding)](https://youtu.be/gmiN3BnOu3w)
- [Which exhaust vent hood is the right vent hood for your house?](https://youtu.be/z0ifAl7saaw)
- [Window Install AFTER HomeWrap® - Air and Water Barrier DuPont" Tyvek®](https://youtu.be/JhXx__AMzTo)
- [J-channel vinyl siding around exhaust vent?](https://www.house-improvements.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8822)
- [Amazon review referenced by forum post](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R1QI73J06VFK22)

Comment: "(Mods, if this is "double posting" please feel free to combine the two)" If you'll take the [tour], you'll see that this is _exactly_ the way you should post multiple questions. Tying multiple questions into one post can get your question closed, or at a minimum breaks the system because if two people each provide a good answer for different parts of the question, how do you chose which to accept as the "most correct/helpful" one? You can't and the question remains open forever. _Please_ take the [tour]...

Comment: Need to make sure that the house wrap and flashing sit _under_ the bottom flange of the vent so that any water that makes it through the sealing at the top runs to the outside of the housewrap instead of being stuck between it and the wooden wall sheathing.

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks! Does this look like the correct approach? https://imgur.com/a/lM7fa0W

Comment: Why would you cut back so much siding?  At most you should only cut it back enough so that the "block" part of the vent will fit through the hole.

Comment: @Huesmann my understanding is I need to open enough room to surround the vent flange with flashing tape once it's secured to the wall

Comment: @Shouldhavedoneitmyself but you can just cut the siding where necessary.  Then remove (and put back after) any lengths that block your access to the vent flange—or just peel the siding back.  No need to cut and replace big chunks.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry that's a mistake in my choice of words. I intend to cut only to fit the block and merely peel the adjacent siding back. Thanks!